# Pandas group-by select closest number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Lets say I have the following data frame:

```
d = {'store': ['s1', 's1', 's2', 's2',], 'code': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'range': [1, 2, 3,2]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


print(df)
    store   code     range  
0     s1      a        1           
1     s1      b        2              
3     s2      a        3           
4     s2      b        2
```

For each store I want to pick the code where the range is closest to a chosen value n, for example lets say n=3

The result would be the following:

```
    store   code     range  
0     s1      b        2           
1     s2      a        3
```

A few small details to note, in the actual dataset range is not an integer its a double and there are three codes per store (a,b,c), only showing two here for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try subtracting the `n` value from `range` and getting the indexes of the `min` value per store using [`groupby idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-idxmin) on `df['store']`:

```
n = 3
new_df = (
    df.loc[(df['range'] - n).abs().groupby(df['store']).idxmin()]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

```
  store code  range
0    s1    b      2
1    s2    a      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
n = 3
df.loc[df.assign(diff=(df['range']-n).abs()).groupby('store')['diff'].idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
  store code  range
1    s1    b      2
2    s2    a      3
```